# VLC : Couldn't load vlcjni error after load

Tags: android, vlc

I download VLC source code from 
https://github.com/mstorsjo/vlc-android

I compile it without problem but when I run, get same error in logcat:
**Couldn't load vlcjni : findLibrary returned null**

Find same title here :

[Develop with LibVLC for android on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20617049/develop-with-libvlc-for-android-on-windows)
.

can anyone help to fix problem?

Thank you!